# How to make a specific complicated binding of two tables

Tags: r, dataframe, binding

I have a single column dataframe with all possible IDs:

```
comment       ID 
 used         a1
 used         a2
 used         b1
 not_used     b11
 not_used     c1
```

I get dataframe from my database with same column "ID". But in that dataframe, not all IDs might be. Here is example of that table:

```
ID    value
a1     18
a2     10
b1     10
```

I want to bind those tw tables in that way, so IDs which were not in my table have value zero. And also I want to keep column comment accordingly. So, how to bind these two tables to get this:

```
comment       ID    value
 used         a1     18
 used         a2     10
 used         b1     10
 not_used     b11    0
 not_used     c1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `full_join()` from `dplyr` and trick the `NA` with `replace()`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df1 %>% full_join(df2) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Output:

```
   comment  ID value
1     used  a1    18
2     used  a2    10
3     used  b1    10
4 not_used b11     0
5 not_used  c1     0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data1
df1 <- structure(list(comment = c("used", "used", "used", "not_used", 
"not_used"), ID = c("a1", "a2", "b1", "b11", "c1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

#Data2
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("a1", "a2", "b1"), value = c(18L, 10L, 
10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This task can be solved by data.table library.

```
library(data.table) #import library
setDT(df1) #Set data.table structure to dataset
setDT(df2) #Set data.table structure to dataset
merge.data.table(df1, df2, by = c('ID'), all = TRUE)
# inner join to get only result that match both datasets
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `merge` from `base R`

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'ID', all = TRUE),
      value = replace(value, is.na(value), 0))
```

-output

```
#   ID  comment value
#1  a1     used    18
#2  a2     used    10
#3  b1     used    10
#4 b11 not_used     0
#5  c1 not_used     0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(comment = c("used", "used", "used", "not_used", 
"not_used"), ID = c("a1", "a2", "b1", "b11", "c1")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))


df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("a1", "a2", "b1"), value = c(18L, 10L, 
10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```